# How to reuse memory with PHP objects

Tags: php, oop, memory

I have a piece of code, which has to handle several hundred objects (images), but after the 77th instance it bumps into the 128 MB memory limit and dies.

The objects instaced by a static call which returns a new instance of the object:

```
foreach($imags as $imageId)
{
    $image = IMP::getById($imageId);
    ...
    ...
}
```

The problem is, that after each loop iteration the memory never gets freed, as seen below, each new imageobject eats up helluva lot of memory.

Memory usage:

```
...
20971520
22282240
23855104
25427968
27000832
28573696
30408704
32243712
34078720
35913728
38010880
39845888
...
```

Any ideas how can the object memory space be reused?

Comment: You likely have left a (global) (static) variable that keeps an instance of the object and therefore the memory is not freed.

Comment: If I do a forced GC, the memory gets freed, but GC takes a lot of time :(.

Comment: Please add the information about the forced GC to your question (and generally you should show more code, what you describe hangs a bit in the air). And GC *should* not take a lot of time. Maybe you needlessly create circular references somewhere?